await has no effect on this kind of expression - but clearly does
I recently added jsdocs to my project and since then I have eslint telling me that
'await has no effect on this kind of expression'
const result = await someAsyncFunction(); // await has no effect
console.log(result.property);

Removing the await keyword however has the effect that console tries to log before result has resolved.
I know that that eslint complains because someAsncyFunction does not return a promise itself but has async functions inside of it.
async function someAsyncFunction(){
  const response = await fetch('dataset');
  const anotherResponse = await fetch('anotherDataset')
  const merged = combineDatasets(response, anotherResponse)
  return merged;
}

Am I really supposed to wrap this function in another Promise?
async function someAsyncFunction(){
  return new Promise(async(resolve) => {
    ...
    resolve(merged);
  })
}

Ignoring the warning about 'await having no effect' works without problems - every time. How ever it makes me think that my approach and / or my understanding of promises is way of.
Maybe you could point me in the right direction here.

I recently added jsdocs to my project It sounds like those docs may have given your IDE the false impression that someAsyncFunction does not return a promise. Can you show the jsdocs for someAsyncFunction?

/** @returns {customType} */ But merged (when just returned) is not a promise in that sense right?

If you change it to @returns {Promise<customType>}, does that work? The function is an async function so it returns a promise, you just need your jsdocs to reflect that i think.

"I know that that eslint complains because someAsncyFunction does not return a promise itself" That's plain wrong. All async functions return a promise.

JSDoc is not actually typing the code but merely annotation, you shouldn't be using its warnings to change your code but only your description/annotation of the code. If you want an actual type system use TypeScript.

@AKX thanks for clearing this up. I get it - but then again wouldn't the proper way be to resolve(merged) instead of just returning. The fact that I just return it, is what made me believe its not a promise

your await is already unwrapping the returned promise, and regardless, no matter what you do before returning, as an async function it will always return a promise.

Clear example in the docs: JSDoc: @async

@user3086509 a new promise accepts a function that itself accepts two parameters: a resolver and a rejecter (e.g. new Promise((res, rej) => res(null)); resolves to null immediately). You can call those parameters like functions to pass them the values you are resolving or rejecting the promise with. When you use async on a function, you are implicitly doing the equivalent of res(/* return value */) inside a new Promise, unless you are already returning a Promise. It's wrapped-if-necessary, but always a Promise return value.


Am I really supposed to wrap this function in another Promise?

No need to do so. This is done by your async function as it always returns a promise and resolves this promise on a successful/non-erroneous return:


/**
 * Returns a promise that is successfully resolved as soon as "merged" is returned
 * @returns {Promise} You might want to also type the response: Promise<typeOfMerged>
 */
async function someAsyncFunction() {
  const response = await fetch("dataset");
  const anotherResponse = await fetch("anotherDataset");
  const merged = combineDatasets(response, anotherResponse);
  return merged;
}

/**
 * await is needed if you want to use "merged".
 * If you want to work with the not yet resolved promise, you remove await here.
 */
const result = await someAsyncFunction(); 
console.log(result.property);




Every Async Function returns a promise
And so does someAsyncFunction() by returning merged
// await unwraps the promise 
const result = await someAsyncFunction()

So jsdoc complained because my comment was wrong
/** @returns {Promise<customType>} */ 

